# Issue while creating azure container instance

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I am able to run the docker image and container works fine in local as expected.

After pushing the docker image to Azure Container Registry, I've tried to run through Azure Container Instance and throwing below error. Whereas the PS file is located in the WORKDIR and its working in local. Would be great if someone can help.

**Dockerfile**

```
WORKDIR c:/inetpub/wwwroot
ENTRYPOINT powershell .\InitializeContainer
```

**Error:**

```
    .\InitializeContainer : The term '.\InitializeContainer' is not recognized as 
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\InitializeContainer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\InitializeContainer:String) [ 
   ], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Can you show the whole Dockerfile?

Comment: can you try `powershell .\InitializeContainer.ps1` (adding .ps1)

Comment: **CharlesXu** and **silent**, thanks for your response. I found the issue, for some reason the ps files was not copied :(